# Are there any studies on health effects of pipe smoking once a week or less?

Tags: smoking, statistics

**Are there any studies on health effects of pipe smoking once a week or less?**

There's very little out there on rare pipe smokers, and as such I've been unable to find any studies along these lines for myself.

([Related question here.](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/5915/are-there-any-studies-on-health-effects-of-rare-smoking) This question is different to that one, as this one is specific to pipe smokers, and that one is concerned with studies of even lower frequency of smoking.)